# IIS 7.5 not redirecting on 403 error

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, custom-error-pages, http-error

I have custom error pages setup for my asp.net application unfortunately they don't appear to be working for 403 error in one circumstance. I believe that the request is not getting to my ASP.NET code. The problem caused is by the following URL: (I'm pretty positive its caused by the combination of ..%5C )

www.site.com/..%5CStorage%5CDocuments%5C8849145d-174a-41ab-9676-0ae19d6ab741

It gives an error message that looks like below:
[image: Error Page]
I have the following in my web.config file:

```
<httpErrors   existingResponse="Replace" defaultResponseMode="Redirect" errorMode="Custom">
  <remove statusCode="404" />
  <error statusCode="404" path="/ErrorPages/Oops.aspx" responseMode="Redirect"/>
  <remove statusCode="401" />
  <error statusCode="401" path="/Account/Login.aspx" responseMode="Redirect"/>
  <remove statusCode="501"/>
  <error statusCode="501" path="/ErrorPages/Oops.aspx" responseMode="Redirect"/>
  <remove statusCode="411"/>
  <error statusCode="411" path="/ErrorPages/Oops.aspx" responseMode="Redirect"/>
  <remove statusCode="403"/>
  <error statusCode="403"   path="/ErrorPages/Oops.aspx" responseMode="Redirect"/>
</httpErrors>
```

AND

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPages/Oops.aspx">
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/ErrorPages/Oops.aspx"/>
</customErrors>
```

Hope someone can help I'm loosing hair over this one....

Comment: are others errors redirecting correctly ? and are you sure it is IIS 7.5 ? because httpErrors works IIS 7+